# How to create session only once, when the server starts?

Tags: java, session, servlets, chatbot, init

I'm creating a chatbot for a java application with Watson Assistant, the servlet code:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String sessionIdOut = "";               
    String question = req.getParameter("message");       
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    // Set up Assistant service.                
    IamOptions iamOptions = new IamOptions.Builder().apiKey("<apikey>").build();
    Assistant service = new Assistant("2018-09-20", iamOptions);
    service.setEndPoint("https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/");
    assistantId = "<assistantid>"; 

    // Create session.             
    CreateSessionOptions createSessionOptions = new CreateSessionOptions.Builder(assistantId).build();
    SessionResponse session = service.createSession(createSessionOptions).execute();
     sessionId = session.getSessionId();            

    // Suppress log messages in stdout.
    LogManager.getLogManager().reset(); 

    // Initialize with an empty value to start the conversation.
    String inputText = question;


    // Send message to assistant.
    MessageInput input = new MessageInput.Builder().text(inputText).build();
    MessageOptions messageOptions = new MessageOptions.Builder(assistantId, sessionId)
                                                          .input(input)
                                                          .build();
    MessageResponse response = service.message(messageOptions).execute();


    // Print the output from the dialog if any. Assumes a single text response.
    List<DialogRuntimeResponseGeneric> responseGeneric = response.getOutput().getGeneric();
    if(responseGeneric.size() > 0) {
        System.out.println(response.getOutput()/*.getGeneric().get(0).getText()*/);
        String answer =  response.getOutput().getGeneric().get(0).getText();
        // set up the response
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        // write out the response string
        res.getWriter( ).write(answer);                
    }

    // Prompt for next round of input.
    System.out.print(">> ");                
}
```

Currently, the servlet always creates a new session and sets up the assistant when the GET request arrives from the user interface. I want it to create a new session and set up assistant service only once when the server starts.

Tryed to solve the problem by adding init() function, and writing the session creation and assistant setup code inside that init() function like this:

```
@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {

    // Set up Assistant service.                
    IamOptions iamOptions = new IamOptions.Builder().apiKey("<apikey>").build();
    Assistant service = new Assistant("2018-09-20", iamOptions);
    service.setEndPoint("https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/");
    assistantId = "<assistantid>";  

    // Create session.             
    CreateSessionOptions createSessionOptions = new CreateSessionOptions.Builder(assistantId).build();
    SessionResponse session = service.createSession(createSessionOptions).execute();        
     sessionId = session.getSessionId();
    super.init();       
}
```

But it doesn't work, when I write a question in user interface, it sends me back 500 status code.

Comment: you need to declare SessionResponse session on class level and if you want session should be created on load of application you need to define load-on-startup any positive no in web.xml

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem!

Working code looks like:

```
package com.jtypebot;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.assistant.v2.Assistant;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.assistant.v2.model.CreateSessionOptions;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.assistant.v2.model.DeleteSessionOptions;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.assistant.v2.model.DialogRuntimeResponseGeneric;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.assistant.v2.model.MessageInput;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.assistant.v2.model.MessageOptions;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.assistant.v2.model.MessageResponse;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.assistant.v2.model.RuntimeIntent;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.assistant.v2.model.SessionResponse;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.security.IamOptions;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.LogManager;

@WebServlet("/JtypeBot")
public class JtypeBot extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;            

String sessionId;  
String assistantId;
Assistant service;  

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */

public JtypeBot() {
    super();            
}

@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    super.init();           

    // Set up Assistant service.                
    IamOptions iamOptions = new IamOptions.Builder().apiKey("<apiKey>").build();
    service = new Assistant("2018-09-20", iamOptions);
    service.setEndPoint("https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/");
    assistantId = "<assistantId>"; // replace with assistant ID

    // Create session.             
    CreateSessionOptions createSessionOptions = new CreateSessionOptions.Builder(assistantId).build();
    SessionResponse session = service.createSession(createSessionOptions).execute();        
    sessionId = session.getSessionId();         
    System.out.print(sessionId);        
}   

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String sessionIdOut = "";                            
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String question = req.getParameter("message");    

    // Suppress log messages in stdout.
    LogManager.getLogManager().reset(); 

    // Initialize with empty value to start the conversation.
    String inputText = question;        

    // Send message to assistant.
    MessageInput input = new MessageInput.Builder().text(inputText).build();
    MessageOptions messageOptions = new MessageOptions.Builder(assistantId, sessionId)
                                                          .input(input)
                                                          .build();                 

    MessageResponse response = service.message(messageOptions).execute();

    // Print the output from dialog, if any. Assumes a single text response.
    List<DialogRuntimeResponseGeneric> responseGeneric = response.getOutput().getGeneric();
    if(responseGeneric.size() > 0) {
        System.out.println(response.getOutput()/*.getGeneric().get(0).getText()*/);
        String answer =  response.getOutput().getGeneric().get(0).getText();

        // set up the response
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

        // write out the response string
        res.getWriter( ).write(answer);                
    }

    // Prompt for next round of input.
    System.out.print(">> ");                
}   
}
```